# Is there a way to split data in r by column then run the same set of commands for each data set

Tags: r

I have a table of data made in excel that i converted to a txt file.
The command I'm using will only let me run it if I have only two columns. I transposed my data into columns but now I need to somehow split it all up so every column 2 to column 189 is a different table with column 1 staying the same in all.

Is it possible to then run the exact same set of commands over and over again for the 188 tables created and save the resulting data into a separate file (or better yet substitute some of the obtained values into an equation).

Sorry if the question is too long or ridiculously easy - I'm a complete newbie to anything beyond basic analysis.

Happy to try and learn other programs if it will solve my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following in base R (I use the built-in `mtcars` data.frame as an example)

```
df <- mtcars
lst <- apply(rbind(1, 2:ncol(df)), 2, function(idx) df[, idx])
```

This returns a `list` of `data.frame`s with columns (1,2), (1,3), (1,4) and so on, of the original `data.frame`.

```
str(lst)
#List of 10
# $ :'data.frame':  32 obs. of  2 variables:
#  ..$ mpg: num [1:32] 21 21 22.8 21.4 18.7 18.1 14.3 24.4 22.8 19.2 ...
#  ..$ cyl: num [1:32] 6 6 4 6 8 6 8 4 4 6 ...
# $ :'data.frame':  32 obs. of  2 variables:
#  ..$ mpg : num [1:32] 21 21 22.8 21.4 18.7 18.1 14.3 24.4 22.8 19.2 ...
#  ..$ disp: num [1:32] 160 160 108 258 360 ...
# $ :'data.frame':  32 obs. of  2 variables:
#  ..$ mpg: num [1:32] 21 21 22.8 21.4 18.7 18.1 14.3 24.4 22.8 19.2 ...
#  ..$ hp : num [1:32] 110 110 93 110 175 105 245 62 95 123 ...
# $ :'data.frame':  32 obs. of  2 variables:
#  ..$ mpg : num [1:32] 21 21 22.8 21.4 18.7 18.1 14.3 24.4 22.8 19.2 ...
#  ..$ drat: num [1:32] 3.9 3.9 3.85 3.08 3.15 2.76 3.21 3.69 3.92 3.92 ...
# $ :'data.frame':  32 obs. of  2 variables:
#  ..$ mpg: num [1:32] 21 21 22.8 21.4 18.7 18.1 14.3 24.4 22.8 19.2 ...
#  ..$ wt : num [1:32] 2.62 2.88 2.32 3.21 3.44 ...
# $ :'data.frame':  32 obs. of  2 variables:
#  ..$ mpg : num [1:32] 21 21 22.8 21.4 18.7 18.1 14.3 24.4 22.8 19.2 ...
#  ..$ qsec: num [1:32] 16.5 17 18.6 19.4 17 ...
# $ :'data.frame':  32 obs. of  2 variables:
#  ..$ mpg: num [1:32] 21 21 22.8 21.4 18.7 18.1 14.3 24.4 22.8 19.2 ...
#  ..$ vs : num [1:32] 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 ...
# $ :'data.frame':  32 obs. of  2 variables:
#  ..$ mpg: num [1:32] 21 21 22.8 21.4 18.7 18.1 14.3 24.4 22.8 19.2 ...
#  ..$ am : num [1:32] 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
# $ :'data.frame':  32 obs. of  2 variables:
#  ..$ mpg : num [1:32] 21 21 22.8 21.4 18.7 18.1 14.3 24.4 22.8 19.2 ...
#  ..$ gear: num [1:32] 4 4 4 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 ...
# $ :'data.frame':  32 obs. of  2 variables:
#  ..$ mpg : num [1:32] 21 21 22.8 21.4 18.7 18.1 14.3 24.4 22.8 19.2 ...
#  ..$ carb: num [1:32] 4 4 1 1 2 1 4 2 2 4 ...
```

It's not easy to operate on the `list` of `data.frame`s using a function from the `*apply` family.

Comment: R's recycling strikes again!! Thanks @thelatemail:-)

Answer (score 1):

To generate the basic combinations, you could use `Map`:

```
Map(cbind, df[1], df[-1])
```

To apply a function to each combination you would need to edit the function a bit:

```
Map(function(a,b) fun(cbind(a,b)), df[1], df[-1])
```

Or add another level of looping with `lapply` if you want to keep the code compact.

```
lapply(Map(cbind, df[1], df[-1]), fun)
```